# SFSafariViewController not opening page in iOS 17, lags, and shows black screen

Tags: swift

I'm encountering an issue with `SFSafariViewController` in my Swift project on iOS 17. When I attempt to open a link using `SFSafariViewController`, the page doesn't load properly. Instead, I experience lag, and eventually, a black screen is shown.

Here's the code I'm using to open the link:

```
func openHelp() {
    guard let url = URL(string: Links.myLink.rawValue) else { return }
    let vc = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
    sourceViewController?.present(vc, animated: true)
}
```

I have not encountered this issue on previous iOS versions.
Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I had the following extension, that worked perfectly before iOS 17. For some reason it caused my problem, so I had to remove it.

```
extension SFSafariViewController {
    override open func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this problem in my current project on iOS 17. Views using SFSafariViewController are not working, even FacebookSDK.
I tried creating a new project and opening SFSafariViewController on iOS 17 and it ran fine, also try opening Facebook Login view using SFSafariViewController and it still runs fine.
There's something wrong with the current project, I'm still trying to investigate. If you have any clue, please also let me know.
Thank you

**Updated:**
I have worked around and was able to fix it by removing all of the values in the Debug and Release section of the Other Linker flags and then replacing them with a single $(inherited) value. Let me know if this helps fix.
[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer, unfortunately this didn't help

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was that under iOS 17, I always had a blank page. However, the same code works well on earlier versions, and my web page is always open in my custom Safari. After some testing, it turned out that I didn't include a 'super.viewWillAppear' in the 'viewWillAppear' method.
I hope this was clear, and it will resolve your issue